# Line-break after opening quotation mark in iOS 14

Tags: ios, keyboard

I’ve noticed a behavior lately that I find rather strange. In the middle of a paragraph, if a word coming right after an opening quotation mark (like the word ‘this’ in “this short quote”) doesn’t fit in the line and so has to start a new line, the quotation mark would not be moved along with that word. In other words, the line-break gets inserted right between the quotation mark and the word even though there was no spacing there — see the screenshot.

[image: So in iOS 14, when I type this “verylongword in quote,” the opening quotation mark is not kept on the same line as the word coming after it.]

I must admit that I am a non-native, although quite proficient, English speaker, so I may just be unaware of this grammatical/typesetting rule, but, personally, that would be a weird rule.

Also, I’m not sure how old this bug actually is, maybe I just never wrote up such examples before.

My questions:

1. Is this actually a bug or is it correct typesetting?
2. If it is a bug, have you seen it before? Has anyone reported it to Apple before?
3. If no one’s reported it yet, what would be a more accurate description of the incorrect behavior? Or is my description clear enough?

The screenshot was made in the Notes app, but I’ve also seen it, for example, in iMessage or in Facebook’s Messenger:

[image: If I try typing a “verylongword in quote” in iMessage, I get a similar result]

[image: If I try typing a “verylongword in quote” in Messenger, the line-break is also misplaced.]

Comment: Safari 14 on macOS 10.14.6 does the same, on this very site. I just spotted it ten minutes ago. I know of no fix.

Comment: I also find this very annoying, and it’s still there after several years. Did you ever find out more about this?

Comment: @LGP not really, I largely forgot about this. However, I've just tried replicating this issue on iOS 17.0.3 and I couldn't, it seems to have been fixed since. I'm not sure at what point it got fixed, though.